# How is context.sync() resp. Word.run() related to the undo-function?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

In my Add-In I replace the text of a lot of content controls. It would be nice to allow the user to undo all of these replacements at once, if he accidentally clicked something.

But I observe varying behavior: Sometimes STRG+z undos all of the replacements, sometimes only a few and sometimes only one. Sometimes it lets the user jump to the first page, which is also anoying.

How are these functions related? I don't seem to find anything about this in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The undo behavior in Word today does not offer fine-grained control.  It generally "just works", but different APIs will record the undo operations with varying degrees of verbosity, and it's not something where any explicit work has gone into it (yet).  There is no atomicity to the operations, either (i.e., a `sync` that fails halfway will still keep the document in whatever state the failed operation left it at).

We are aware of the gap, and are exploring some ways for solving the issue, but it's a non-trivial amount of work to support it across the different hosts and platforms.

(FWIW, Excel has the opposite problem of being very predictable in its undo policy, but that policy is simply to blow away the undo stack completely, anytime that an API makes a *write* operation.  Again, we're actively working on figuring out a solution.)

Comment: It would be great if whatever option gets decided on could come with some guidance about how many operations can be rolled up (if it ends up working similar to the COM api version).

Comment: Sure, we'll keep it in mind.  If you have some feedback/thoughts re. how the COM one works today, and what are some limitations/pros/cons (my main expertise is in Excel, not Word), that would be useful to know, too).

Comment: The biggest problem with the existing one is it's scoped to the application and not scoped to the document.  Also if you try and put thousands of actions inside a single transaction word can slow down pretty dramatically.  Finally the existing com one lets you nest undo actions inside of undo actions, but there isn't really any guidance in the documentation that tells you why you should or should not do this.